# checkmarx exception for dynamic DML, Ex: insert operation on input from method param

Tags: checkmarx

I am getting error as "SampleClass.cls Method sampleMethod at line 3 of classes\SampleClass.cls gets user input from the strVar element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated, and is eventually used in a database query in method sampleMethod at line 3 of classes\SampleClass.cls. This may enable an SOQL Injection attack. line no: 2, 5, 6" in checkmarx report.

```java
public class SampleClass {
    public String strVar {get; set;};
    public void sampleMethod(){
        if (strVar != null){     
            strVar = strVar.trim();
            List<String> varList = strVar.split(' ');   
            //logic
            String str1;
            String qString =  'select id, Description FROM Account';
            if (varList.size() == 1){
                str1 = varList.get(0);
                queryStr+= ' and (Account.Name like \'%' + str1 + '%\')'; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you're at risk for SOQL injection, hence this error. You've mitigated it somewhat by only allowing a single word, but you might still run in problems if someone tries to use an apostrophe ("single quote"), such as `'hello`. This would render the query filter as `Name LIKE '%'hello%'`, which would cause an error. You need to remember to use `String.escapeSingleQuotes`.

```
queryStr+= ' and (Account.Name like \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(str1) + '%\')';
```

See this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/secdev_inject_prevent_soql_injection).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. got it.